# HttpRedirect configured in ApplicationHost.config fails to rediret in Windows Server 2012

Tags: redirect, iis, windows-server-2012

I am trying to redirect URL https://hostname/ to https://hostname/ABC.
It always worked on 2008 server. But since we upgraded to Windows 2012 server, the redirect doesn't happen. We get error now that directory listing is not enabled. This works on my local development box.

```
<location path="Default Web Site/iisStart.htm">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="false">
            <add wildcard="*" destination="/ABC" />
        </httpRedirect>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Note: There are no rewrite rules configured and this is the only httpRedirect section configured

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the root cause.

iisStart.htm is not configured as default document in Default Web Site. Since https://hostname doesn't default to https://hostname/iisStart.htm, the redirect doesn't happen.